# Download a pdf file from android application using Jsoup

Tags: java, android, download, jsoup

I would like to download a pdf file from my android application. I want to download it using jsoup because I have to post username, password and cookies, so I have done it with jsoup. I have check the site adn saw that I have to connect at the login page and post: username,password,cookie and a variable next with the internal link of the pdf file. I have done it with jsoup but now I don't know how to download this file at my android device. I prefer, if it's possible, when it will download to appear on the notification bar of my device.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @ASP Thank you for the quick response, I'll check and write again.

Comment: @ASP I have try this one you give with the jsoup but it isn't work for me. :( I would be grateful for some other answer!